# Simplest way to implement PDA/Ipad/2Desktop connect to MSSQL Server?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, ipad, windows-phone-7

i received a requirement of the application is designed for all employee in the company, employee may use window phone, Ipad or Iphone. additionally, they can access to the application with 2 on-desk desktop.

May i know what is the simplest way to implement all device able to access the database located at stand-alone server ? how if using WCF + WPF for desktop application and Silverlight + WCF for those device ?

Comment: @sam B, @dan andrews, How you think of i queue the message to desktop and send through desktop ?

Comment: How do you want to Queue?  And for what benefit?

Comment: @dan andrews, i want to make something like... POS, customer can send the order to printer and database via device, then counter use another desktop to access DB for checkout

Comment: Have a print me WCF service that prints what is sent to it.  Then you won't need the desktop for anything.  Everything could be handled in the website then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how Silverlight works on the Iphone.  But you could use WCF with a web page.

Comment: I didn't want to say, "doesn't work" as I was thinking of MONO.  It is clearly safe to say, "It generally doesn't work"

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to target Iphone, Ipad and Windows Phone, your easiest option is to stick to plain ASP.Net web sites. Most AJAX functionnality works great with IPhones/IPad/WP7.

Answer (score 1):

Next to REST/JSON you might consider WCF Data Services. For the client to be able to be use on all platforms HTML is the safest bet.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a IIS Windows based service to deliver data for iPhones using REST and JSON. I created an application template in VS2010 from the "Online Templates" called ".NET 4.0 WCF REST Web Service".

Then, I used the templates in the Service1.cs file that follow this pattern:

```
public class MyReturnObj {
   string MyField1;
   string MyField2;
}
```

This is an example of a simple return object, but the object can be complex
with properties that are List or whatever.

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetMyData?User={User}&Password={Password}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public MyReturnObj getMyData(string User = "", string Password = "")
{
    MyReturnObj ro = new MyReturObj()
    {
          MyField1 = @"somethign",
          MyField2 = @"more things"
    }

    return ro;
}
```